# Find count of maximum

Tags: sql

Suppose I have table with following values

```
A         B           C
------------------------
5        ABC         $20
3        BCD         $40
5        BCD         $40
2        ABC         $20
5        ABC         $30
```

How to write query which would return count of maximum, suppose for column A
it should return value 3 that is count for max which is 5.

Comment: Didn't any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 4):

You can use sub-query like this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNTS FROM Table1
WHERE A = (SELECT MAX(A) AS AD FROM Table1)
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a7a7/19)

Answer (score 2):

One way (not sure it's the fastest):

```
SELECT A, count(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 2 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Although not as typical this works as well

(Self anti-join on an inequality)

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(t1.a) AS COUNTS 
FROM Table1 t1
   LEFT JOIN Table1 t2
    ON t1.A < t2.A
WHERE 
      t2.a is null
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a7a7/25)